# Storing data in WEB API so that it can be used later

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

There is a website for which I am writing web services using C# MVC WEB API so that mobile app could use them for storing and retrieving data. now there is a problem that in one of the methods there is a value that I have to use in another method. I need to access that value. I have read answers of others regarding same issue using session handling but it is also not a good approach. How should I get that value? So far I have done this.

```
public Object carYears(string Carmade, string CarModel)    //not working
{
    List<object> list = new List<object>();
    int? manid = Convert.ToInt32(Carmade);
    int? modid = Convert.ToInt32(CarModel);
    var md = db.des_texts.Where(x => x.TEX_ID == modid).SingleOrDefault();
    var manufac = db.manufacturers.Where(x => x.MFA_ID == manid).SingleOrDefault();
    var mod = (from modl in db.models
               join mn in db.manufacturers on modl.MOD_MFA_ID equals mn.MFA_ID
               join cd in db.country_designations on modl.MOD_CDS_ID equals cd.CDS_ID
               join dt in db.des_texts on cd.CDS_TEX_ID equals dt.TEX_ID
               where (mn.MFA_ID == manid) && (cd.CDS_LNG_ID == 4) && (modl.MOD_PC == 1) && (dt.TEX_TEXT == md.TEX_TEXT)
               orderby mn.MFA_BRAND, dt.TEX_TEXT
               select new { modl.MOD_ID, mn.MFA_BRAND, dt.TEX_TEXT, modl.MOD_PCON_START, modl.MOD_PCON_END }).FirstOrDefault();

    //TempData["modelid"] = mod.MOD_ID;    <-- i need this value in another method
    var session = HttpContext.Current.Session;
    if (session != null)
    {
        if (session["modelid"] == null)
            session["modelid"] = mod.MOD_ID;

    }
```

can this TempData be used for this purpose?? One more thing I have made session and stored value in it but still I am unable to access this value in the other method.

Comment: I think either you should resolve this problem in service level or have two separate calls or actually think over architecture as it compromises the Web Api RESTful approach.

Answer (score 0):

Create a DTO class as

```
public class ExampleRequest
{
  public int ExId {get; set;}
...Add more types required if any
}
```

in the first method

```
public Object carYears(string Carmade, string CarModel)
    {
//previous code
ExampleRequest request = new ExampleRequest();
request.ExId = mod.MOD_ID;
otherMethod(request);
}

public bool otherMethod(ExampleRequest request) {
int modId = request.ExId;
//otherCode
return true; //or false
}
```

Comment: otherMethod(request); won't be appropriate as both methods are returning data from the server and i need this MOD_ID in the other method because ii have to write a query that needs this id..

Comment: but this DTO class could used just to store that id and i can access it in the other method too without calling that method ..

Comment: the otherMEthod is an example as i have no clue what the second method looks like. and yes, you can use the DTo class in other methods the same way.

Answer (score 0):

You should not rely on session for this I don't think. Unless the mobile app is storing the ASP.NET Authentication key and passing it with each request. For an ASP.NET MVC website this is an almost "out of the box" feature but you can't rely on session for a mobile app client, whether the API is supposed to respect REST or not. I do not think Web API and ASP.NET will ensure that the same session for each request of the same mobile app client will be used.

The `carYears` method could return the `modelid` back to the mobile app, the `otherMethod` can require the `modelid` as a parameter and then the mobile app can include the `modelId` in the next request to the `otherMethod`, the signature would be:

```
public returnType otherMethod(int modelId){}
```

Otherwise, your `otherMethod`is just a private "helper" method to the caller, `carYears`, and would have the signature, obviously no need for session as you are just passing the `modelid` in `carYears` to `otherMethod`.

```
private returnType otherMethod(int modelId){}
```

Comment: i had this thing in my mind too but just asked this question so might there be a way around..